# how to use recursion to get the minimum value of an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

So my current assignment is to make a recursive function that iterates through an array and returns it's smallest value.

I've looked at similar questions but they don't quite match up with mine because I can only have the array and the size of the array as parameters.

This is the code I have so far

```
private static int findMin(int[] data, int size){
    int i = 0;
    if(size == 1){
        return data[0];
    }else if (data[0] < data[i++]){
        return findMin(data, size-1);

    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

My main issue is that I'm not sure how to compare the values of the array to return the smallest value. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!
EDIT: forgot to mention it was java

Comment: what code would you write if you were allowed to use whatever parameters you like?  Maybe we can give you a hint on how to fix that to use the parameters you're allowed.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to ask: is this C# or Java? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Please, take a look at my solution, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
else if (data[0] < data[i++]){
        return findMin(data, size-1);
```

to something like

```
else if (data[size-1] < data[0])
        data[0] = data[size-1];   
return findMin(data, size-1);
```

The idea is to recurse on a smaller array that still contains a candidate for the mininum element.

Comment: For zero-based arrays, I think that would be `data[size-1]`, yes? `data[size]` would be _beyond_ the array bounds.

Answer (score 0):

With *just* the array details (i.e., not being able to pass the current minumum *down* through levels), the following pseudo-code<sup>(a)</sup> can do it:

```
def findMin (array, size):
    //if size == 0:
        //doSomethingIntelligent();
    if size == 1:
        return array[0]
    minOfAllButLast = findMin (array, size - 1)
    if array[size-1] < minOfAllButLast:
        return array[size-1]
    return minOfAllButLast
```

In other words, the minimum of the list is the lesser of the last element and the minimum of the *rest* of the list, with the terminating condition being a list of size one where the single element is obviously the minimum.

That obviously doesn't handle zero-sized lists, how you do that depends on whether you want to return an indicator or throw an exception or something else. The commented code is one way in which you could handle that though that is in itself inefficient since it only need check once:

```
def findMin (array, size):
    if size == 0:
        doSomethingIntelligent();
    return findMinNonEmpty (array, size);

def findMinNonEmpty (array, size):
    if size == 1:
        return array[0]
    minOfAllButLast = findMinNonEmpty (array, size - 1)
    if array[size-1] < minOfAllButLast:
        return array[size-1]
    return minOfAllButLast
```

---

But I have to inform you, this is *not* a good use case for recursion. Most algorithms that reduce the solution space slowly (such as one item per level) rarely are.

The best use cases are those that reduce the solution space *quickly,* like a binary search which *halves* the solution space each time.

If you're using this for education, that's fine, just keep in mind that it's not the way you would do it in the real world. For finding a minimum, the iterative solution is the most efficient way:

```
def findMin (array, size):
    if size == 0:
        doSomethingIntelligent();
    currMin = array[0]
    for index in 1 thru size - 1 inclusive:
        if currMin > array[index]:
            currMin = array[index]
    return currMin
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I usually only give pseudo-code for assignments since implementing it in your language of choice will make you a better code-cutter :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Your second case needs to use the *last* element of the array, not the first, since you can only decrease the size. I'm assuming we are allowed to use `int.MaxValue` as "infinity" (the minimum of an empty list).

```cs
private static int findMin(int[] data, int size) {
    if (size == 0) return int.MaxValue;
    return Math.Min(data[size - 1], findMin(data, size - 1));
}
```

**Edit**: since we now know it's Java and the above is C#, there's some *very* minor changes required (the algorithm remains the same, of course):

```java
private static int findMin(int[] data, int size) {
    if (size == 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    return Math.min(data[size - 1], findMin(data, size - 1));
}
```

And for completeness, we can write out the `min` operation between the two values explicitly if we're not allowed to use any library help (even though `min` adds nothing to the recursion and isn't "cheating"):

```
private static int findMin(int[] data, int size) {
    if (size == 0) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int last = data[size - 1];
    int minOfAllButLast = findMin(data, size - 1);
    return last <= minOfAllButLast ? last : minOfAllButLast;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should be what you are looking for:

```
private static int findMin(int[] data, int size){
    return ((size < data.length - 1) ? (Math.min(data[size], findMin(data, size + 1))) : (data[data.length - 1]));
}
```

Call it with `findMin(data, 0)`

It is basically starting from 0. While the size of the visited subset of `data` is smaller than the index of the last element, the function returns the minimum of the current element and the minimum of the elements being deeper in the array, otherwise (end-sign) returns the current element. If you call the method by passing an array of 1 elements, then the end-sign will be instantly recognized. If you call it with an array having 0 elements, then an exception will be thrown, which is normal, since you cannot determine a minimum element from an empty set.